# Sendgrid shows different link location on hover

Tags: hyperlink, html-email, sendgrid

I use sendgrid to blast emails out for different clients. I have one master account and then a few sub accounts. Each account has a subdomain and a unique ip address assigned to it.

Lately I have been having an issue where I link an image to Company A's website and it goes to it, but when you hover over it, Company B's website shows. Not sure why. Links are correct and I am not doing anything fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Likely this is due to the setting of the title attribute in your HTML. I know most GUI editors (WYSIWYG) they will automatically create a title that is the URL inside the a tag.

If you are just changing the URL inside an a tag, then you likely still have the old URL inside of the title attribute of the a tag.

For example:

```
<a href="URL1" title="URL1"><img src="prettyimage.jpg" /></a>
```

If you took that and just replaced URL 1 with URL2 in the href, the title would still display URL1 on hover.

Your options are:

If you design it via WYSIWYG editor:

1. See if your editor allows the option to edit title on a tag
2. Remove the the link completely and create a new link each time

If you hand code:

1. Edit the title each time you change the href
2. remove the title attribute completely from the a tags

Comment: Whats weird is that when you hover over the link its showing the wrong link at the bottom of the browser in the loading status bar

Comment: is there any way you could provide the source for the email?